# Military like sci fi about DoD or possibly DHS agent main antagonist is a geneticist

Tags: story-identification, military-sf

I can’t remember if this is a series or if it was one book but I remember it being about a very talented, possibly ex military man getting recruited to some secret agency that said they were part of the Department of Defense or quite possibly the Department of Homeland Security. Pretty sure it isn’t anything to do with James Rollins and Sigma force but I remember there being some kind of geneticist that was the main antagonist and for some reason I remember these platinum haired twins as part of the story and their genes were spliced with snakes or some other animal.

Comment: The snake DNA splicing gets us our sci-fi aspect. Were those male or female twins?

Comment: One was a male and one was female

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! It’s the Joe Ledger series written by Jonathan Maberry! Fantastic books and I highly recommend them. The book I was specifically remembering was The Dragon Factory